# Create a Button that's border incrementally diminishes onClick and fires an event on time '0'

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I found this great tool but it's awkward to implement in my project: https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer

I want to create a reusable button component that onClick, starts a similar countdown effect with its border, giving the user a chance to 'undo' their decision (similar to forwarding a message in fb messenger). I can figure out the react logic but no clue where to start with css

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the code of the component you mention, I noticed it uses an SVG element with animated stroke to create and animate the circular progress bar.

This article is my favourite one about this specific problem:
https://css-tricks.com/building-progress-ring-quickly/

Here is the code from that article for future reference. This is not my code, kudos to the original author of the article:

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;

function setProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
setProgress(input.value);

input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (input.value < 101 && input.value > -1) {
    setProgress(input.value);
  }  
})
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #2962FF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-ring {
  
}

.progress-ring__circle {
  transition: 0.35s stroke-dashoffset;
  // axis compensation
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<svg
   class="progress-ring"
   width="120"
   height="120">
  <circle
    class="progress-ring__circle"
    stroke="white"
    stroke-width="4"
    fill="transparent"
    r="52"
    cx="60"
    cy="60"/>
</svg>

<input
  value="35"
  type="number"
  step="5"
  min="0"
  max="100"
  placeholder="progress"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is a pure css pie timer which looks pretty similar to one of your timers mentioned in the link.

## See it in full screen

```js
var time = 11;



{
  var func = setInterval(function() {
    if (time != 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('time')[0].innerHTML = time;
      time--;
      if (time < 5) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('warning')[0].style.display = "block";
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName('time')[0].innerHTML = "0";
      document.getElementsByClassName('warning')[0].style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(func);
    }

  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.timer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: time 5s infinite;
  margin-left: 570px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
}

.left_progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00d2ff 0%, #3a47d5 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px 100px 200px 0px);
  animation: rotate_right 6s 6s linear both;
}

@keyframes rotate_right {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}

.left_progress_bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px 100px 200px 0px);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: mid-way 4s linear both;
}

.right_progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px 100px 200px 0px);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  animation: rotate_left 6s linear both;
}

@keyframes rotate_left {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.right_progress_bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00d2ff 0%, #3a47d5 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px 100px 200px 0px);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.main_content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: 'arial';
  text-align: center;
}

.timer_content {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.content {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #6B6C6D;
}

.time {
  font-size: 55px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00d2ff 0%, #3a47d5 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.warning {
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  animation: warning_bell 1s infinite;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes warning_bell {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">


  <div class="right_progress_bar">
    <div class="right_progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left_progress_bar">
    <div class="left_progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_content">
    <div class="warning"></div>
    <div class="timer_content">
      <p class="content">You can do in</p>
      <p class="time">12</p>
      <p class="content">seconds</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```